# how to filter and get limit amount of data using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have an array which contains some java script objects and I am using ejs for display data but the problem is - that I have to filter that data in the bases of `req.params.id` and want to next 2 data objects..! after filtering data -- please help

my code is -

```
app.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
  const requestParams = _.lowerCase(req.params.id);

  let obj = blogData.find((o) => o.heading >= "Yoga-During-COVID");
  console.log(obj);
 
  blogData.forEach(function (post) {
    const storedTitel = _.lowerCase(post.heading);
    
    if (storedTitel === requestParams) {
      res.render("blogfullDetail", {
        date: post.date,
        heading: post.heading,
        subheading: post.subheading,
        discription: post.discription,
        discription2: post.discription2,
        author: post.author,
        authorImage: post.authorImage,
        mainImg: post.mainImg,
      });
    }
  });

});
```

data file -

[image]

Comment: Please [do not post pictures of text](/help/how-to-ask), put that text in your post (with appropriate markup). Having said that, I'm not sure I understand your need, can you (in your post) explain what data you have, and what you want your code to do, in order to get the data you need (where you show examples of both the data you have, and the data you need that to become).

Comment: I have array of objects, actually I want to filter that data which is in picture and after filtered need objects which comes after req.params.id value  @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: Can you explain this [in your post](/help/how-to-ask) please. And again, please replace that image with real text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of `findIndex` and `slice`. findIndex returns the index of the matching element and slice returns a sub-array from that index to a computed higher index...

```js
let blogData = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'yoga is good'
  },
  {
    id: 32,
    title: 'yoga helps you stretch'
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    title: 'covid yoga is good too'
  },
  {
    id: 41,
    title: 'no such thing as too much yoga'
  },
  {
    id: 57,
    title: 'is hot yoga too hot'
  }
];

// say you need the post about covid...
let targetTitle = 'covid yoga is good too';
let index = blogData.findIndex(p => p.title === targetTitle);

// with the index, answer a slice of the blogs
// starting at that index, ending 3 later
let posts = blogData.slice(index, index + 3);
console.log(posts)
```